# In PHP, how can I access a child object when I don't know it's name?

Tags: php, object, properties

Using `json_decode`, I've ended up with an object that looks like this:

`$data->foo->bar->1234567->id`

I want to access `id`. There are two problems, both with the number `1234567`:

1. It's an illegal property name.
2. The number will differ each time, and I can't predict what the number will be. I need a way of accessing `id`, even when I don't know the number.

I know I can overcome problem (1) with curly braces, but I don't know how to overcome (2). I don't want to use `get_object_vars`, because the object is likely to be very large, and that function is very slow.

My current solution is simply
`foreach ($data->foo->bar as $id);` but that feels rather hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is using `json_decode(,true)` and then resetting the array, (thus index zero would be a valid property) be an option?

Comment: There should be no way that you want to access something you  don't know what is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above, using `json_decode(,true)` and then resetting.

The example json array looks like:

```
Array (
    [foo] => Array (
            [bar] => Array (
                    [1234567] => Array (
                            [id] => 1234
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The code:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{"foo":{"bar":{"1234567":{"id":1234}}}}', true);

reset($data['foo']['bar']);
$number = key($data['foo']['bar']);

echo $data['foo']['bar'][$number]['id'];
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/Ubzd5Zdz): 1234

Comment: Great. Simple, but effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need the whole array anymore and only want to get the id you can get it like this:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{"foo":{"bar":{"1234567":{"id":1234}}}}', true);

echo array_shift($data['foo']['bar'])['id'];
```

Only works if the unknown key is the first element of bar. array_shift removes the element from $data.